# Distinction between また and も

Tags: grammar, particle-も

I'm very new to Japanese study, so please bear with me...

> 日本語の勉強は楽しいです。 数学の勉強も楽しいです。

In this example, study of Japanese is fun. Study of math is also fun, も is used to indicate that math, similarly to Japanese, is also fun to study. I.e. that studying math shares the characteristic of studying Japanese *already* mentioned. I know this is correct. However, if one wanted to mention a different characteristic of math that has not already been mentioned, by virtue of commenting on Japanese study, could また be used?

For example:

> 日本語の勉強は楽しいです。 また、数学の勉強は難しいです。
> (Study of Japanese is fun. Also, study of math is difficult.)

I'm fairly sure も could not be used here as the two subjects are not sharing the same description. But, am unsure as to whether or not the use of また, to mean also/moreover/furthermore, etc. is correct, or if it is better to just omit また and use two non-linked sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `また` when you are comparing two things that don't share the same description doesn't sound natural. `また` doesn't really connect these two sentences in that case.

It would be...

> 日本語の勉強は楽しいです。でも、数学の勉強は難しいです。
>
> (Study of Japanese is fun. But, study of math is difficult)

because you are comparing two subjects with different descriptions (one being fun but another being difficult).

You could also say...

> 日本語の勉強は楽しいですが、数学の勉強は難しいです。
>
> 日本語の勉強は楽しいけど、数学の勉強は難しいです。
>
> 日本語の勉強は楽しいです。数学の勉強は難しいです。